# Return all objects that include a duck, Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to return all instances of an object that includes a duck.

eg:

```
module FruitDuck
  #code
end

class Apple < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FruitDuck
  #code
end

class Banana < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FruitDuck
  #code
end


a = Apple.new
b = Banana.new
```

Therefore

```
Apple.all -> returns [a]
Banana.all -> returns [b]
```

How can I call:

`FruitDuck.all`, so that it returns `[a,b]`

At the moment I'm stuck at:

`ActiveRecord::Base.subclasses.select { |type| type.ancestors.include?(FruitDuck) }.map(&:all).flatten`

However, this seems fragile

Comment: The code you've posted definitely does *not* behave the way you say it does. `a = Apple.new` will *not* be returned by `Apple.all`. ActiveRecord's class-level methods **query the database**. They do not query in-memory objects. Finding *all instances* of a certain type of object has nothing to do with the functionality ActiveRecord provides. If you're actually after an ActiveRecord solution, you want **Single Table Inheritance** which will let you query all instances of a base class using `BaseClass.all`.

Answer (score 1):

### Invoke #all on Classes with a Mixin

To invoke #all on each class that includes FruitDuck, this will work:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(FruitDuck).flat_map &:all
```

However, it won't really do what you want, since ActiveRecord calls like `Apple.all` will only return apples that have been persisted to the database. It will also *not* return the names of variables which hold objects that contain your mixin.

### Inspecting Instance Variables for a Mixin

To find the names of in-memory variables that have your module mixed in, you must use instance variables rather than local variables for scoping reasons. Then you can do do something like this:

```
@a = Apple.new
@b = Banana.new

instance_variables.select { |v| instance_variable_get(v).class < FruitDuck }
#=> [:@a, :@b]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puts ObjectSpace.each_object(FruitDuck).to_a
```

returns all existing `FruitDuck`s (i.e. those that are currently instantiated in memory).

```
puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |c| c < FruitDuck }.flat_map(&:all)
```

should give you all `FruitDuck` classes, then invoke `all` on it, giving you all instances from the database (assuming all `FruitDuck`s are ActiveRecord models. If not, then this restriction would need to be included.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to retrieve persisted records because of:

```
Apple.all  #=> returns [a]
Banana.all #=> returns [b]
```

You could use the [`included`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-included) callback that is invoked whenever a class includes your module:

```
module FruitDuck
  def self.included(mod)
    @included ||= []
    @included << mod
  end

  def self.all
    @included.flat_map(&:all)
  end
end
```

Be aware that `FruitDuck.all` will execute multiple queries and return the concatenated results in an array. So unlike `Apple.all` or `Banana.all`, it does not return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.